# TFS 2010 Missing Process Templates

Tags: tfs

I am trying to set up continuous integration using  Visual studio 2010 and TFS 2010 and when i try to Create a new build definition, and go to Process Tab, i dont see any templates under the Build Process file(Windows workflow XAML) drop-down.

I have setup a build controller that points to our Team project collection and a build agent, in our TFS server.I am trying to setup a new build definition from my local machine Visual studio and i cant see any default templates under the  Build Process file(Windows workflow XAML) drop-down.

Is there any settings i am missing ?Please let me know. Do i also need to install Visual studio in the TFS Server ?

All i need is whenever someone checks in a file, it should kick off a build and see the status if the build is broken or not !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have a folder inside your Team Project Source Control called:

**BuildProcessTemplates**

[image]

Inside of there should be the following files:

- DefaultTemplate.xaml
- UpgradeTemplate.xaml

There are additional ones in this example, but you should have those two from the install.

If you have this folder and still cannot see anything in that dropdown let me know and we can take it from there.  What most likely happened is you or someone on your team saw the folder and deleted it or moved it thinking it its placement wasn't important in the project. Or perhaps deleted the xaml files inside there.

The process section uses that folder and all files within it to display on that prompt.

Comment: Thanks.I Opened up Team explorer from Visual Studio and expanded my Project and opened Source control.But all i see is my project folder and Trunk and all my files under Trunk.Am i looking in the wrong place ?

Comment: I will post a picture for you.

Comment: If for whatever reason the are missing you can download them online or a quick solution is also just to create another team project, copy and paste them over to the project you are working on.